# What's a proper way to make React component to re-render every minute?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-redux

I'm working on a React-Native project using TypeScript, and I'm facing an issue where I want a component to rerender every minute, even if the state derived from a selector does not change. The output of my selector changes due to a `dateProvider.getNow()` function.

Here's a simplified version of my component:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const viewModel = useSelector((rootState) => selectHomeViewModel(rootState, dateProvider))

  // rest of the component code
}
```

The homeViewModel:

```
import { RootState } from '../../../../core/_redux_/createStore.ts'
import {
  BlockSession,
  blockSessionAdapter,
} from '../../../../core/block-session/block.session.ts'
import { formatDistance, isBefore } from 'date-fns'
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {
  Greetings,
  HomeViewModel,
  HomeViewModelType,
  SessionBoardMessage,
  SessionBoardTitle,
} from './home-view-model.types.ts'
import { DateProvider } from '../../../../infra/date-provider/port.date-provider.ts'

function greetUser(now: Date) {
  const hour = now.getHours()

  if (hour >= 6 && hour < 12) return Greetings.GoodMorning
  if (hour >= 12 && hour < 18) return Greetings.GoodAfternoon
  if (hour >= 18 && hour < 22) return Greetings.GoodEvening
  return Greetings.GoodNight
}

function generateTimeInfo(now: Date, start: Date, end: Date) {
  return isActive(now, start, end)
    ? 'Ends ' +
        formatDistance(end, now, {
          addSuffix: true,
        })
    : 'Starts at ' +
        start.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0') +
        ':' +
        start.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')
}

function recoverDate(now: Date, time: string) {
  const [hours, minutes] = time.split(':').map(Number)

  const todayWithNewTime = new Date(now.getTime())
  todayWithNewTime.setHours(hours)
  todayWithNewTime.setMinutes(minutes)

  return todayWithNewTime
}

function formatToViewModel(blockSessions: BlockSession[], now: Date) {
  return blockSessions.map((session) => {
    const start = recoverDate(now, session.start)
    const end = recoverDate(now, session.end)

    const timeline = generateTimeInfo(now, start, end)

    return {
      id: session.id,
      name: session.name,
      minutesLeft: timeline,
      blocklists: session.blocklists.length,
      devices: session.devices.length,
    }
  })
}

function isActive(now: Date, start: Date, end: Date) {
  return !isBefore(now, start) && isBefore(now, end)
}

export const selectHomeViewModel = createSelector(
  [
    (rootState: RootState) => rootState.blockSession,
    (_state: RootState, dateProvider: DateProvider) => dateProvider,
  ],
  (blockSession, dateProvider): HomeViewModelType => {
    const blockSessions = blockSessionAdapter
      .getSelectors()
      .selectAll(blockSession)

    const greetings = greetUser(dateProvider.getNow())

    const NO_ACTIVE_SESSION = {
      title: SessionBoardTitle.NO_ACTIVE_SESSIONS as const,
      message: SessionBoardMessage.NO_ACTIVE_SESSIONS as const,
    }

    const NO_SCHEDULED_SESSION = {
      title: SessionBoardTitle.NO_SCHEDULED_SESSIONS as const,
      message: SessionBoardMessage.NO_SCHEDULED_SESSIONS as const,
    }

    if (!blockSessions.length)
      return {
        type: HomeViewModel.WithoutActiveNorScheduledSessions,
        greetings,
        activeSessions: NO_ACTIVE_SESSION,
        scheduledSessions: NO_SCHEDULED_SESSION,
      }

    const activeSessions = blockSessions.filter((session) => {
      const now = dateProvider.getNow()
      const start = recoverDate(now, session.start)
      const end = recoverDate(now, session.end)
      return isActive(now, start, end)
    })
    const formattedActiveSessions = formatToViewModel(
      activeSessions,
      dateProvider.getNow(),
    )

    const scheduledSessions = blockSessions.filter((session) => {
      const now = dateProvider.getNow()
      const start = recoverDate(now, session.start)
      const end = recoverDate(now, session.end)
      return !isActive(now, start, end)
    })
    const formattedScheduledSessions = formatToViewModel(
      scheduledSessions,
      dateProvider.getNow(),
    )

    if (!activeSessions.length)
      return {
        type: HomeViewModel.WithoutActiveWithScheduledSessions,
        greetings,
        activeSessions: NO_ACTIVE_SESSION,
        scheduledSessions: {
          title: SessionBoardTitle.SCHEDULED_SESSIONS,
          blockSessions: formattedScheduledSessions,
        },
      }

    if (!scheduledSessions.length)
      return {
        type: HomeViewModel.WithActiveWithoutScheduledSessions,
        greetings,
        activeSessions: {
          title: SessionBoardTitle.ACTIVE_SESSIONS,
          blockSessions: formattedActiveSessions,
        },
        scheduledSessions: NO_SCHEDULED_SESSION,
      }

    return {
      type: HomeViewModel.WithActiveAndScheduledSessions,
      greetings,
      activeSessions: {
        title: SessionBoardTitle.ACTIVE_SESSIONS as const,
        blockSessions: formattedActiveSessions,
      },
      scheduledSessions: {
        title: SessionBoardTitle.SCHEDULED_SESSIONS as const,
        blockSessions: formattedScheduledSessions,
      },
    }
  },
)
```

And here's the dateProvider:

```
export class RealDateProvider implements DateProvider {
  getISOStringNow(): string {
    return new Date().toISOString()
  }

  getNow(): Date {
    return new Date()
  }
}
```

I tried to use `useEffect` with `setInterval` to force a re-ender every minute, but I couldn't make it work, and I'm not sure if this is the best approach or if there's another way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I chose:

```
  const [now, setNow] = useState<Date>(dateProvider.getNow())
  const viewModel = useSelector<
    RootState,
    ReturnType<typeof selectHomeViewModel>
  >((rootState) => selectHomeViewModel(rootState, now))

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setNow(dateProvider.getNow())
    }, 1_000)
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId)
  }, [now])
```

My issue was coming from using `createSelector` from Redux Toolkit that memoized my `dateProvider`. Therefore, the useEffect dependency array never changed. So I change the signature of the selector to accept a Date object instead of a DateProvider.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with the need or use case to force rerender a component *more often* than is required (*i.e. when a state or props value changes*), but if this is something you want to do then I believe you were on the correct path with trying to use a `useEffect` hook and an interval timer.

Try the following implementation:

```js
// Some state to update to trigger component rerenders.
const [, setRerender] = React.useState(0);

// Mounting effect to instantiate 1-minute interval to
// force rerender component.
React.useEffect(() => {
  // Handler to enqueue a local state update to trigger a rerender
  const forceRerender = () => setRerender(c => c + 1);

  // Instantiated interval to trigger state update
  const timerId = setInterval(forceRerender, 60000);

  // Cleanup function to clear any running timers
  // when the component unmounts.
  return () => {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  };
}, []);
```